# Typescript + requirejs: How to handle circular dependencies?

Tags: requirejs, typescript

I am in the process of porting my JS+requirejs code to typescript+requirejs.
One scenario I haven't found how to handle is circular dependencies.

Require.js returns undefined on modules that are also dependent on the current and to solve this problem you can do:

*MyClass.js*

```
define(["Modules/dataModel"], function(dataModel){
  return function(){
    dataModel = require("Modules/dataModel");
    ...
  }
});
```

Now in typescript, I have:

*MyClass.ts*

```
import dataModel = require("Modules/dataModel");

class MyClass {

  dataModel: any;

  constructor(){

    this.dataModel = require("Modules/dataModel"); // <- this kind of works but I lose typechecking
    ...
  }
}
```

How to call require a second time and yet keep the type checking benefits of typescript? dataModel is a module { ... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the type using what you get from `import` i.e

```
import dataModelType = require("Modules/dataModel");

class MyClass {

  dataModel: typeof dataModelType;
```